# Как хранить баланс пользователя в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Интересует, как хранить баланс пользователей в MySQL? Если во FLOAT, то он округляется и значения постоянно получаются неправильные. Пробовал типы DOUBLE и REAL, тоже самое. Значения всегда такие: 1.2899999 и т.д..

Comment: [Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Деньги следует хранить в типах с фиксированной точностью. В SQL это [numeric](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

Хранить информацию о денежном показателе необходимо только в целых типах (например. выраженную в копейках - или в даже в долях копейки - в зависимости от того какая точность). Тем более что способы округления могут отличаться от математики по законодательству

Comment: Зачем, если есть типы с фиксированной точнотью?

Comment: ну если по простому - хотя бы ради скорости вычислений. Про точность надо лезть глубоко и много писать. И вы эти данные будете передавать в другие программы которые тоже будут считать в целых единицах. Значительно меньше шансов что на каком-то этапе кто-то захочет "вернуться" к плавающей точке.

Comment: В копейка хранить есть смысл если не нужна точность то сотых, тысячных и тд. В банковских система я пока встречал только тип с фиксированной точностью. Есть свои проблемы, но их легко можно избежать при грамотном подходе. Тем более у ТС 1.2899999....